# Can pdf kit save images from a url?

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

I have a node.js application in which I'm using pdfkit to generate pdf documents. I want to be able to include images from a url in the pdf. I cant save the image to the file system because my runtime environment is read only and pdf kit seems to find the images to embed from a file system directory. Is there a way I can use an url in pdf kit to embed an image?

---

[Here](https://github.com/kimenye/pdfkit). This guy modified the pdfkit to include that functionality.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible with the current implementation. But I can tell you it's easy to modify the source and implement this feature.

Comment: I assume this question is about [this pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/image.coffee#L13) is where it reads the file. You can for example change it to `@contents = filename` or anything you want it to be.

Comment: @alFReDNSH one might even argue that would be a cleaner interface.

Comment: Is it possible through the pdfkit available through node without editing?

Answer (score 3):

PDFKit now supports passing buffers to the `doc.image` method instead of a filename. See [this](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/commit/f20e777dee3b259daca1a9096201124199e94c76) commit. So you could do as the other answer suggests, and download the image from the URL yourself, and then pass the buffer directly to PDFKit instead of saving it to a file first.

Answer (score 1):

you can use http.get:

```
    http.get('YOUR URL TO GET THE IMAGE').on('response', function(res)
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
       buffer += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){

    fs.writeFile('PATH TO SAVE IMAGE', buffer, 'binary', function (err) {
        if (err){
           throw err;
        }
        doc = new PDFDocument({ size: 'LETTER or any other size pdfkit offer' });
        doc.image('PATH TO SAVE IMAGE', 0, 0, { fit: [WIDTH, HEIGHT] })
        .fontSize(10).text('text 1', 100, 170)
        .fontSize(16).text('text 2', 60, 120)

    }); //After file is download and was write into the HD will use it

}).end(); //EO Downloading the file
```